# display jquery color picker on top rather than bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, color-picker

I am using [this](http://colpick.com/) Color Picker plugin, it seems to be appearing alright but all i want is to make it appear on top of field rather than bottom. This is what it looks like

[image]

This is my html field

```
<input type="text" name="slide_background" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose background color" id="picker">
```

and this is my `JavaScript`

```
<script>
    $(function ($) {
        $('#picker').colpick({
            layout:'hex',
            submit:0,
            colorScheme:'dark',
            onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el,bySetColor) {
                $(el).css('border-color','#'+hex);
                if(!bySetColor) $(el).val(hex);
            }
        }).keyup(function(){
            $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);
        });
    });

</script>
```

I will really appreciate if anyone can assist me in this.

**UPDATE**

Following css fixed it for me

```
.colpick_hex { 
margin-top: -235px !important;
}
```

Comment: hmm, this is the css issue and you have not tagged css but js...

Answer (score 3):

Try this script,

```
$(function ($) {
        $('#picker').colpick({
            layout:'hex',
            submit:0,
            colorScheme:'dark',
            onBeforeShow:function() {
                 var top = $('.colpick_dark').position().top - 200;
                 $('.colpick_dark').css({top:top+'px'});
            },
            onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el,bySetColor) {
                $(el).css('border-color','#'+hex);
                if(!bySetColor) $(el).val(hex);
            }
        }).keyup(function(){
            $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);
        });
    });
```

Adjust the top of the picker by adjusting the `200` in the code. Check onBeforeShow function while initializing.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to play around with it, it seems the color picker disappears when i try this

Comment: Ok. I have updated the class I think you need to change the class of the whole colorpick instead of 'colpick_dark' in my code

Comment: Thank you so much @Manu M, I ended up achieving it via `css` `.colpick_hex { margin-top: -235px !important;}`

Answer (score 1):

You will just need to place it using css, if you use your inspector you can see the id of the picker is colpick_abs - so...

```
    #colpick_abs{
        top: -300px;
        bottom: 300px;
    }
```

This should slide it up 300 pixels, and you can adjust that number until you like it.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to play around with it, it seems the color picker disappears when i try this

Comment: Thank you @box86rowh, I ended up fixing it via `css` `.colpick_hex { margin-top: -235px !important;}`